# IIS failing after machine name change

Tags: windows, iis, windows-server-2016

If I change the machine name of a Win2016 server (as a precursor to putting it on the domain) this causes the 'Default Website' in ISS v10 to fail.

I have not created any other website, virtual directory or AppPool. There are just the objects and settings that IIS creates when it is first installed.

As soon as I navigate to 'http://localhost' in a browser the 'DefaltAppPool' will stop and several errors will be generated in the 'Event Viewer' (from the 'WAS' source in the 'System' log and the 'IIS-W3SVC-WP' soruce in the 'Application' event log). These errors indicate the 'worker process failed to initalise and therefore could not be started'.

If I change the machine name back to the old name then the IIS appPool works as normal.

It suggest that the 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' is somehow hard-coded to a specific machine name.

I have also tested a Win2008 R2 VM with IIS v7 and the same issue occurs. I have also found this with another Win2016 VM that has never had IIS installed before.

It seems that even if IIS has never been installed before if the machine's name has been changed at any time IIS will not work.

Although I am familiar with IIS I am not an expert but I would expect that when I have installed IIS as a brand new role that the 'Default Website' and 'DefaultAppPool' that are created as standard should work without any further configuration.

**Can you please advise how I can investigate / resolve this ?**

============ Update 07-12-2018 =================

I have been doing some more testing and I think I may have found the trigger (although cause & resolution still unknown).

The original name of the unchanged Win2016 VM was 'WSVR2016-02016' and I tried changing the name (but keeping the VM in a workgroup) and after each change restarted the machine then when it came backup I made sure the IIS 'DefautlAppPool' was started in IIS Manager, visited "http://localhost" in the Chrome borwser and then checked the IIS Manager to see if the AppPool had stopped.

I tried each of the following names (all still in a Workgroup) and they all worked: 
WSVR2016-O2018 |
WSVR2016-O2018T |
TEST-PAL-AD |
TEST-PAL-ADV2

I then tried changing the networking of the VM to Bridged rather than NAT but keeping the last machine name - still it worked.

I then tried, with the same 'TEST-PAL-ADV2' machine name, connecting the VM to our domain and when I went to 'http://localhost' the IIS AppPool stopped !

**So it looks like connecting to the domain is what causes the problem - but how ?**

(I did notice that each time I changed the machine name the name of the server retained the old name in IIS. So the top 'connection' node was saying "WSVR2016-02016 (TEST-PAL-ADV2\Administrator" - but it did the same through all the name changes and did not stop IIS working)

Answer (score 0):

There may be settings or policies pushed out by the domain that are preventing the ApplicationPoolIdentity from running. I would suggest changing the DefaultAppPool pool to run as local system and inquire with your domain admins regarding any policies that might be interfering. You may also be able to discern some of that yourself by running gpresult

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I look after the servers and domain for my company but to my knowledge we have never adjusted the default group policy.

Can you suggest what settings could possibly be interfering with the AppPool ?

I would point out that: 
a) this would have to be a setting they would affect the apppool of the default IIS install under Win 2008 R2 (IISv7) and Win 2016 (IISv10)
b) as it is on completely different servers (installed at different times) this has to be something generic and 
c) this happens even when a new appPool is created by an IBM script.

Many thanks

Comment: Check the Local Security Policies and verify that Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Logon as a Service isn't being controlled. [See here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2017/02/04/how-iis-interferes-in-group-policy-log-on-as-a-service/).

Comment: The domain has 'Logon As Service' set. I will check the local GPO but wouldn't the local apply wether the machine was in a domain or not ? When in a workspace (i.e. not on a domain) the AppPool works fine - it is only when the machine is in the domain that there is an issue. If I need to add the 'DefaultAppPool' to the domain 'Logon As Service' how would I do this as that is not a normal user account ?

Comment: Look at the policy before you join it to the domain and then compare it to after. The IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool (or whatever account is actually running the pool) needs to be in the policy. Also, have you looked at the security logs when the application tries to start?